# Record type is not compatible with specific object type

Tags: typescript

Why this piece of code does not work? beta indeed has keys of type string and their values are compatible (id is indeed number type, and temp is indeed number type), and most of all Record makes values of all keys any, and any should be compatible with everything.

```
const alpha:  Record<string, any> = {
  id: 1,
  temp: 2
};

const beta : {
  id: number;
  temp: number
} = alpha;
```

Then why it says that?

> Type 'Record<string, any>' is missing the following properties from
> type '{ id: number; temp: number; }': id, temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beta` expects `id` and `temp` properties.

Because you have provided explicit type for `alpha`, TS treats `alpha` as `Record<string, any>` and not as `{id: number; temp: number}`.

Hence, there is no guarantee that `Record<string, any>` contains `id` and `temp`.

You need to remove explicit type from `alpha`.

Try to avoid explicit types in such cases, TS most of the time should do the work for you.

```js
const alpha = {
  id: 1,
  temp: 2
};

const beta : {
  id: number;
  temp: number
} = alpha;
```

This is how TS treats these variables:

```js
declare let alpha: Record<string, any>;

declare let beta: { id: number; temp: number };

alpha = beta // ok

beta = alpha // error
```

As you might have noticed, `beta` is assignable to `alpha`, so you can provide explicit type `Record<string, any>` for `alpha` object.

But it does not work in opposite direction - `alpha` is not assignable to `beta` because `beta` is a subtype of `alpha`

Treat `alpha` as a super type and `beta` as a subtype